# How to query multiple post types and multiple post states

Tags: get-posts

This following produces an empty array:

```
$args2 = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'paged'          => 0,
    'orderby'        => 'post_date',
    'order'          => 'DESC',
    'post_type'      => array( 'carellcars', 'ccf', 'attachment' ),
    'post_status'    => array( 'publish', 'inherit' )
);

$posts_array2 = get_posts($args2);
```

Changing the `post_type` and `post_status` to a single string (only one post_type, one post_status) produces results. Is my syntax wrong? Or how can I query multiple post types and post states at once?

Comment: What function gets `$arg2` passed to? `get_posts()`? `WP_Query`? Where exactly are you executing this code?

Comment: I'm executing the code in a php script inside public_html directory.    $posts_array2 = get_posts($args2);

Comment: Can you maybe paste all the relevant parts in your question?

Comment: Ah sorry, no need. You already said, single values work. So it's not your script.

Comment: My development environment is WordPress version 4.4.11 .  Do you know if that supports array values in the arguments?

Comment: Yeah, I'd say so. 4.4. isn't that old. I found tutorials from 2015 and questions from 2013 where they already passed arrays. Did you try to query every single post type, too? To validate that every single one of them would you return something? Did you also tried just one post type and still an array of post states? Have you already tried to use an array with just one post type? Maybe we can track this down systematically.

Comment: Have you tried the same in a fresh vanilla WP 5 installation? Or maybe in a local copy of your site updated to v5?